# What good software is available for editing RAW photo files?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management, editing

I have a DSLR (Canon 550D) and since I'm taking my first steps in the world of RAW photography I don't know which would be a good program to use to edit these files. I've tried [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org/) and [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) but wasn't satisfied. I'm sure there must be better software out there...

Comment: Look at "4 Great Tools For Editing RAW Photos In Linux" - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-great-tools-editing-raw-photos-linux/

Comment: You can try krita.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like rawtherapee. You may want to give it a shot. There is also UFRaw, but I personally don't like it as much.

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install rawtherapee
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw
```

respectively.

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at Darktable. It's an excellent RAW editor. To install  Darktable in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install darktable
```

[image: Darktable]

[image: Darktable]

Answer (score 1):

The Gimp. To install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Thanks Jaen, but I've already been using the GIMP, Picasa and also digiKam. I was thinking about perhaps something unpopular, but better for this use.

Comment: Gimp doesnt support raw files directly. You need to convert to a compatible format